# Validation unique values from array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a `{{ Form::textarea('name') }}` for add an array.

In a controller I use:

```
$input = $request->all();
$name = explode(PHP_EOL, $input['name']);

$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => Rule::unique('table1')->where(function ($query) {
        global $name;
        $query->whereIn('name', $name);
    })
]);
```

But it does not work. How to validation array for unique values?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Doesn't work because **name** is a single string, not an array

Comment: Just a tip : if you want to use `$name` inside of the anonymous function, add `use ($name)` like this : `function($query) use ($name){ // ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy approach. If you want better control and ability to use this with the `validate` method then i'd suggest creating a custom validation rule.

```
$data = [
    'name' => explode(PHP_EOL, $request->input('name'))
];

$validator = \Validator::make($data, [
    'name.*' => 'unique:table1,name',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Handle failed logic
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Maybe you know. I use return `redirect('...')->withErrors($validator)                ->withInput();` for output errors. It output errors as `The name.0 has already been taken`. How to show the value instead of `name.0`.